# VirtualBox shared clipboard with images / rich text?

Tags: windows, images, clipboard

I've got a Windows XP system running in VirtualBox 4.x on OSX on a Mac. I like the clipboard sharing function, however, it applies only to text. Did I miss a special option?

Is there any other way to share clipboards with image data across these systems? I had a look at http://synergy-foss.org/ - but that seems to be too much just to share clipboards and will most likely slow my system down, won't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the record, one year after the OP's question ;-).  But well, this is an interesting point...

1. **No**, **VirtualBox** shared clipboard does *not* (read: never did)  allow to share objects, files or images between guests/host.
2. **Yes synergy** will happily share images (but not files AFAIK) across heterogeneous systems.
3. However, if you run VirtualBox in your main workspace or don't have a second monitor, the situation will probably be confusing (I actually never tried to run synergy in a guest, just imagining) because there will be two conflicting [virtual] mouse:

   - the synergy captive mouse enters in action only if you [attempt to] "cross" the boundary of your synergy server monitor,
   - so the virtualBox guest addition shared clipboard will have the last say, and we are back to square one.

If someone ever tries this hybrid, please publish the outcome. Or any better solution for that matter.