# Transfer image clipboard between host and VirtualBox guest?

Tags: virtualbox, images, clipboard

Is there anyway to transfer clipboard content of image format, JPEG, bitmap or whatever, to or from the VirtualBox guest instances?

Comment: This was answered here (voted to close):  http://superuser.com/questions/42134/virtualbox-shared-clipboard

Comment: The question is actually different in this context, Randolf. I'm afraid there's an actual difference between clipboard support for text and image in VirtualBox, as you shall see from my answer.

Comment: @A Dwarf:  I'll accept that (+1 for your answer and also for your comment).  Now, if only I could remove my close vote (there doesn't seem to be an option for this).

Comment: Indeed. For some strange reason there isn't any way. But don't worry about it. :) Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VirtualBox shared clipboard with images / rich text?](http://superuser.com/questions/246514/virtualbox-shared-clipboard-with-images-rich-text)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VirtualBox support for clipboard sharing is indeed still lacking a formal support for graphics. Officially it only supports text at this time. But if you are under a Windows host, and only under a Windows host, it will support images.

See: [Shared Clipboard and Graphics](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=35227)