# Transfer rich text, image clipboard between Windows guest and Linux host?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, clipboard, microsoft-onenote-2016

This question is similar to 
[Transfer image clipboard between host and VirtualBox guest?](https://superuser.com/questions/311740/transfer-image-clipboard-between-host-and-virtualbox-guest)

However, I want to know if there is ANY virtualization solution can do this. Answers to the above question suggest that VirtualBox cannot do this.

Also, I only care by Windows guests and Linux Hosts. More specifically, I want to copy rich text (text with hyperlinks and formatting) from Onenote running on Windows to Zotero running on the KUbuntu host. Also, I want to copy screen clippings from Spectacle in KUbuntu host to Onenote running on Windows guest.

Comment: This is on the roadmap for Synergy, but its not there yet.   Presently Synergy only transfers text between "monitors" on different machines.  Virtualisation doesn't come into it.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks. I never thought that Synergy could solve this problem. I am looking forward to the future releases of Synergy. The current version (1.8.2) seems to not properly copy hyperlinks -- the link is either lost or rendered as <a href =...> ...</a> when copied across computers via Synergy.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that VirtualBox is capable of transferring images copied to clipboard between guest and host when bidirectional keyboard is enabled. I have done something similar to what you are trying to achieve with OneNote running in a VM, except in my case it was with Evernote. I could easily copy image in host,  paste it in Evernote and annotate it, and copy the annotated image back from guest os into host.  I was running a Windows 7 virtual machine in Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: which version of virtualbox were you using?